# replace() method is not replacing inputs

Tags: javascript, html, variables, replace

What's supposed to happen is certain profanity typed in and submitted by the user is supposed to be replaced with the censored word.

However, that's not the case. It shows the word without the censor.

Should I use the if/else statements to make this work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
      var result = document.getElementById('clean');
      /* Fake 'bad words' for illustration */
      var a = text.replace("ack", "a**");
      var ba = text.replace("bandaid", "b******");
      var bi = text.replace("butch", "b****");
      var f = text.replace("frack", "f****");
      var p = text.replace("pee", "p**");
      var s = text.replace("shoot", "s****");
      var c = text.replace("cart", "c***");
      var n = text.replace("night", "n****");

      result.innerHTML = text;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="input"></textarea>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction();" />
  <p id="clean"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Replace only works for one instance of the target string. Try `text = text.split('ass').join('a**')` instead.

Comment: [You MUST read this...](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are assigning the same value in `clean` which you get from your `input` try this to show your result in `clean` applied on the `input'

```
function myFunction() {
        var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('clean');
        text = text.replace("ack","a**");
        text = text.replace("bandaid","b******");
        text = text.replace("butch","b****");
        text = text.replace("frack","f****");
        text = text.replace("pee","p**");
        text = text.replace("shoot","s****");
        text = text.replace("cart","c***");
        text = text.replace("night","n****");

        result.innerHTML=text;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked however @tewathia answered that first haha

Answer (score 4):

`replace` returns a *new* string but does not modify the original.

This means, you should work with the returned value.

In this case, `text = text.replace(..)`

Edit:
Also, you might consider using regular expressions for this: `"hello world".replace( /world/g, 'foo' )`, so that multiple instances of a search pattern will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, I have rewritten the function for ease in sue.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('clean');
        var Clean =  new Array("ack", "bandaid", "butch", "frack", "pee", "shoot", "cart", "night");
        var len = Clean.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len;i++){  
              text = AddHide(Clean[i], text);
        }
        result.innerHTML=text;
    }

    function AddHide(Text, String){
        if(String!=""){
            var StringLen = parseInt(Text.length)-1;
            var First = Text.charAt(0);             
            for(var k=0; k<StringLen;k++){                
                First +="*";
            }           
            String = String.replace(Text,First);
        }
        return String;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: @SunilDevre: if you do clean up offensive words in a post, do so in context. Not just this answer, but all answers and the question as well.

Comment: sure. But i didn't find any in question...